# jqGrid Insert New Row Custom

Tags: insert, jqgrid, row

I have looked around and have yet to find a decent answer.

I wish to add a new row into my grid from my own custom button, without using their add buttom or edit forms.

Something like:

```
$("#grid").jqGrid('insert',{"id","col1","col2"});
```

I want to be able to programatically insert new rows and not have to use their form.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Byron

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why do you not use `addRowData` method (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods)? Do you want do something more as to add the data?