# Add row in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid and it's working fine.

I have a scenario where I have to add a blank row in jqGgrid instead of a popup to add the row.

How can I do it?

Comment: i didnt understand wat you mean to say..

Comment: please help...i m new to stackoverflow......

Comment: how can i accept the answer...is there ia ny buuton or link to accept the answer

Comment: @Sandy: If the problem is solved you can consider to accept the question (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234 and http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask). If you will read some FAQs (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931) you will understand and use stackoverflow more effective for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use for example [addRowData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods#add_on_grid_methods). Look at [jQGrid, how to add a new row inside the grid, not via a modal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651585/jqgrid-how-to-add-a-new-row-inside-the-grid-not-via-a-modal).

Probably the answer [Spreadsheet-like inline editing in jqGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590594/spreadsheet-like-inline-editing-in-jqgrid/3591915#3591915) and the demo http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ClientsideEditing5.htm could help you also.

Answer (score 0):

from the jqgrid demo page, i see this:

```
jQuery("#list7").jqGrid('setGridParam',{rowNum:15}).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

see:
http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html
manipulating -> set methods

Comment: But i dont want to open the dialog box to add the row..insted i want to add the empty row to the jgrod and then fill the data to the empty row