# jqGrid: how to copy a row?

Tags: php, jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid PHP. When adding a new row (inline mode), how can I pre fill the new row using the same cell data with the last selected row? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a global variable to get the values from last selected row in onSelectRow event like this.

```
var lastsel= jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
```

Now while adding a new row you can use addRowData like this

```
$("#grid").addRowData(rowid,data, position, srcrowid);
```

where data, you can get from lastsel var.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651585/jqgrid-how-to-add-a-new-row-inside-the-grid-not-via-a-modal) for further reference.